# How to android studio run fast?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have a large program in android studio 2.1.0.9. Every time that i want to run my app in android studio I should stay more than 1 hour. How can I speed up it?I also did all step in http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/how-to-make-android-studio-fast.html but did not solve my problem

Comment: what kind of "large program" do you have?

Comment: If I had to guess, your computer does not have nearly enough RAM.

Comment: I am working with telegram source code.

Comment: my computer have 4G RAM and in my pc just android studio is running

Comment: @Tom Telegram probably uses MultiDex builds so builds will last longer. BTW more than 1 hours is too much for a normal build process, also for an app like Telegram. You have to upgrade your RAM, because you have 4G as total but AS can't use all of them.

Comment: @Fondesa Now is not any way expect uprade? Can I clean my RAM?

Comment: @Tom I think it's the only way, or you can "simply" optimize Telegram code to stay under 65k methods to avoid MultiDex, just kidding uh

Comment: in simple project the build time is long? how much?

Comment: in simple project it is about 5 min.

Comment: @Fondesa Thank you for your guidness.

Comment: @Tom 5 minutes without multidex is still too much time, with a good memory management and more ram you can get it to 10 seconds in a normal project

Comment: realy 10 second??????it's very good. thank youuuuuuuuuuu